# Searching products by specific attributes

Tags: mysql, relationship

I've a little Shop-system and now I want to select some product with specific attributes and conditions.

Here my Setup:

table XYZ:

- product_id
- attribute_id
- attribute_group_id

So now I want to select all products which has the attribute-ids 1,3,5 and 7 but not 9 and 2.

How can I do this on a simple way, my first idea was to group it by product id and group_concat the attribute_ids and use "having" to include and exclude the attribute ids I want.

```
SELECT CONCAT('_',GROUP_CONCAT(attribute_id SEPARATOR '_'),'_') as attrs, 
       product_id
FROM my_table
GROUP BY product_id 
HAVING (attrs LIKE '%_1_%' 
        AND attrs LIKE '%_3_%' 
        AND attrs LIKE '%_5_%' 
        AND attrs LIKE '%_7_%')
AND (attrs NOT LIKE '%_2_%' 
    AND attrs NOT LIKE '%_9_%')
```

This works, but there is a better solution, right?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this would help?

SELECT product_id
FROM table_XYZ
WHERE attribute_id IN (1,3,5,7);

Or if you have more ids and what to exclude only a few:

SELECT product_id
FROM table_XYZ
WHERE attribute_id NOT IN (2,9);

Comment: The problem is that i want the product that has all of these attrs, your query will give me each product that has one of these attrs.